# Monodroid - how to debug android widget

Tags: android, debugging, widget, xamarin.android, xamarin

How can I debug android widget using monodev? I'm getting

> Application does not contain a launchable activity

error trying to debug a widget as regular app (`Run -> Start Debugging`).

Answer (score 1):

You must apply the widget to the desktop (launcher) of the device to debug.

The error message is correct and can be ignored as your application does not need a launchable activity if it is only intended to be a widget.

Comment: It looks like I'm missing something. When I start debugging using `Run -> Start Debugging` I get the following messages in Deploy to Device window of the MonoDevelop:

`Detecting installed packages`
`Removing previous version of application`
`Installing application on device`
`Synchronizing assemblies`
`Deployment completed`

After that comes the error:
`Application does not contain a launchable activity`

Note that the debug session does not start. 
I go to the widgets menu of android emulator and drag my widget to the desktop. Since the debug session is not started my breakpoints don't fire.

Comment: This sounds like the problem is that Mono is not properly attaching the session. Sessions should attach by process not by activity. In Eclipse you can select processes manually in DDMS for debugging, also breakpoints work fine in Eclipse for Widgets if I recall correctly. I could not find any resolutions for Mono in a quick Google search so perhaps, if it is an option for you, Eclipse may be a good temporary fix to your problem?